# How can I get URL of next page of a .asp page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, url, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the data at this link: https://thereserve2.apx.com/myModule/rpt/myrpt.asp?r=112

I am able to get the first page, but when I get to next page (using the "next" button at bottom of page) the URL to the next page is generic: https://thereserve2.apx.com/myModule/rpt/myrpt.asp

How can I get a more specific URL to use in my automated scraping effort?

Thanks.

Comment: "Next" button is not a link here, its a control with a postback action. Most asp.net websites use the ViewState to keep track of pages and control values. You will have to post back the ViewState to the server. Use the dev tools to inspect the network and see the parameters for this event. If you use Scrapy, this could be useful: https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/04/20/scrapy-tips-from-the-pros-april-2016-edition/.

Answer (score 1):

Check below HTML and JS code that submits the asp page and go to needed page, "next" button submit the form as you see in below JS an `X999whichpage` is the next page, you need to do the same submit the form with the needed page number.

```js
function submitform2(X999sort, X999field, X999paging, X999whichpage, X999csv, X999action, X999actionfield) {
  document.xxxx2.X999csv.value = X999csv;
  document.xxxx2.X999action.value = X999action;
  document.xxxx2.X999actionfield.value = X999actionfield;
  document.xxxx2.X999sort.value = X999sort;
  document.xxxx2.X999field.value = X999field;
  document.xxxx2.X999paging.value = X999paging;
  document.xxxx2.X999whichpage.value = X999whichpage;
  document.xxxx2.submit();
}
```

```html
<form id="xxxx2" name="xxxx2" action="https://thereserve2.apx.com/myModule/rpt/myrpt.asp?r=112" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="X999myquery" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="X999tablenumber" value="2">
  <input type="hidden" name="X999csv" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="X999sort" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="X999action" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="X999actionfield" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="X999field" value="On">
  <input type="hidden" name="X999paging" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="X999whichpage" value="3">
</form>

Enter Page Number:<input type="text" id="whichpage" value="2"> 
<button onclick="javascript:submitform2('','','On',document.getElementById('whichpage').value,'','','')">Move to Page</button>
```

Another solution without JS

```html
<form id="xxxx2" name="xxxx2" action="https://thereserve2.apx.com/myModule/rpt/myrpt.asp?r=112" method="POST">
<input type = "hidden" name = "X999tablenumber" value = "2" />
<input type = "hidden" name = "X999csv" value = "" />
<input type = "hidden" name = "X999sort" value = "" />
<input type = "hidden" name = "X999action" value = "" />
<input type = "hidden" name = "X999actionfield" value = "" />
<input type = "hidden" name = "X999field" value = "" />
<input type = "hidden" name = "X999paging" value = "On" />
<input type = "text" name = "X999whichpage" value = "3" />

<input type="submit" value="Go To Page" />
</form>
```